# Scrapy - Request URL not correct

Tags: url, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to send a request with scrapy using this code:

```
import scrapy
import json

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["www.drivy.com"]

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' : 1,
    }

    start_urls = ['https://www.drivy.com/search.json?latitude={}&longitude={}&start_date=2019-05-06&start_time=09:00&end_date=2019-05-06&end_time=18:00']

    with open('C:/Users/coppe/drivy/communes.json') as json_file:  
        locations = json.load(json_file)[0:2]

    def start_request(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            for city in self.locations:
                url = start_url.format(city['lat'],city['long'])
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url=url, 
                    callback=self.parse,
                )

    def parse(self,response):
        yield {'url':response.url}
```

Briefly I want to format the URL in `start_urls` with data contained in a JSON file. In the URL I want to fill this: `latitude={}&longitude={}` by replacing the curly brackets by some numbers. These number are in the following JSON file in the keys `'lat'` and `'long'`:

```
[
{"city": "Anvers  ", "region": "R\u00e9gion flamande", "lat": "51.217", "long": "4.4"},
{"city": "Zoersel", "region": "R\u00e9gion flamande", "lat": "51.267", "long": "4.717"},
]
```

However when I run the code above, the request is not correctly formatted it gives me this: `'https://www.drivy.com/search.json?latitude=%7B%7D&longitude=%7B%7D&start_date=2019-05-06&start_time=09:00&end_date=2019-05-06&end_time=18:00'` but it should yield this `'https://www.drivy.com/search.json?latitude=51.217&longitude=4.717&start_date=2019-05-06&start_time=09:00&end_date=2019-05-06&end_time=18:00'`

Anybody as an insight on what's going on here ?

Comment: What does the content of `communes.json` look like? Could you share a fragment of the beginning of the file?

Comment: I've already put it in the post. It is the second piece of code.

Comment: Sorry! Have you tried logging (`self.logger.debug()`) the values of `start_url` and `city` right before building your URL?

Comment: I decoded `latitude=%7B%7D&longitude=%7B%7D&` and got `latitude={}&longitude={}&`. I don't know in which conditions the `format` would fail like this. Try to do what @Gallaecio said, print the variables or use a debugger. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html. Personally I prefer to use `pdb`, just put this line where you want a breakpoint `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: Outside of scrapy everything works, the url is transformed correctly, the loops work. So I guess it has something to do with scrapy or the way the variables are created. I've tried debugging but I found nothing. The JSON is correctly imported but I don't know how to see if the local variable `city` in the for loop is empty or not.

Comment: @M.Coppée I found the error! You misspelled the method `start_requests`, you missed the "s" at the end, so your spider never uses this method and end up using `self.start_urls` without formating it. Also I don't think it's a good idea do use the `with` statement on the class scope, I think it's best to put it on `start_requests` or on the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank you ! Everything works perfectly now. Sorry for this stupid mistake